# The type java.util.Map$Entry cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

Tags: java, eclipse, hashmap, libraries

I am writing a simple Java program on Eclipse.

```
import java.util.HashMap;

public class Demo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HashMap<String, String> hash = new HashMap();
    }
}
```

The above program generates the following errors.

1. The project was not built since its build path is incomplete. Cannot find the class file for java.util.Map$Entry. Fix the build path then try building this project.
2. The type java.util.Map$Entry cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files.

I searched over the internet almost everywhere, but I was not able to correct this.

I have installed Java SE 8u5 (JDK) (http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html?ssSourceSiteId=otnjp)

1. Windows -> Preferences -> Installed JREs shows

a) jdk       C:\Program Files\Java\jdk

1. Project -> Build Path -> Libraries shows

a) JRE system library (jdk)

b) JRE system library (jre8)

Please somebody help me.

**EDIT:** Changing Eclipse version from Helios to Juno solved the problem!

Comment: Have you tried to restart eclipse? I had a similar error for `java.lang.Object` and restarting helped.

Comment: Yes, I tried restarting eclipse. I even restarted my laptop. It did not remove those errors.

Comment: Which version of Eclipse are you using? The release builds do not support Java 8 - you'll need a [patched version of Kepler](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/index-java8.php) or a [Luna developer build](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/index-developer.php).

Comment: I am using Eclipse Helios. Will that be a problem?

Comment: Thanks McDowell, I changed Eclipse version to Juno, now it works!

Comment: I too had same issue with eclipse Indigo + java8. I tried to switch back to JDK 7 and suddenly it is fixed. :)

Comment: Updating the ecj.jar file to version ecj-4.4.2.jar worked for me

Answer (score 20):

I've seen occasional problems with Eclipse forgetting that built-in classes (including `Object` and `String`) exist.  The way I've resolved them is to:

- On the Project menu, turn off "Build Automatically"
- Quit and restart Eclipse
- On the Project menu, choose "Clean…" and clean all projects
- Turn "Build Automatically" back on and let it rebuild everything.

This seems to make Eclipse forget whatever incorrect cached information it had about the available classes.

Comment: I think that is more of that related to eclipse version. So if we can change version which is most supported by Java and Jre 8 that can be resolution of this issue.

Comment: This happen also in Eclipse IBM RAD (Rational), with jdk8, the solution is using jdk7

Comment: @EnriqueSanMartín - You saved my day.. I knew that the problem was with JRE in RAD but I was keep on using different version of JRE8. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: Thanks. Steps worked in 2020-12 version of Eclipse (jdk 11.0.8).