# java.util.Map$Entry unresolved

Tags: java, minecraft

I'm writing a mod (attempting) and an error I have never before seen pops up on my package deceleration screaming

"The type java.util.Map$Entry cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files"

As far as I know requesting help in the direction of minecraft is a no no but I think this qualifies as a java question

```
package com.DGmoN.mysticPower.items;

import java.util.Set;

import com.DGmoN.mysticPower.lib.Strings;

import net.minecraft.creativetab.CreativeTabs;
import net.minecraft.item.ItemPickaxe;
import net.minecraft.item.ItemTool;

public class MPIPickAxe extends ItemPickaxe {

    protected MPIPickAxe() {
        super(ToolMaterial.EMERALD);
        setUnlocalizedName("MysticPickAxe");
        setTextureName(Strings.MODID + ":" + getUnlocalizedName());
        setCreativeTab(CreativeTabs.tabMisc);
    }

}
```

Running jdk1.8.0_05 Eclipse Indigo, I haven't used any thing I know of in the direction of the Map thingy.

Comment: Do you have your JDK installed and setup with whatever tools you are trying to use?

Comment: @NESPowerGlove YES, updated it before asking

Comment: Provide the exact piece of code where you use `Map.Entry` and the stacktrace associated to the problem.

Comment: @Luiggi Mendoza The thing is that I haven't touched the thing. I don't even know what it does, what can cause a ghost error if there even is sutch a thing

Comment: Make sure your project has the desired JDK in the build path.

Comment: @Luiggi Mendoza That I also have done, still not bugging out, a second error that might help is "cant resolve java.lang.CharSequence"

Comment: Being unable to resolve a java.lang class is a sign that, as @LuiggiMendoza said, you're missing the JDK.

Comment: I have explored the faulty jdk but it doesn't resolve my error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a different [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24110620/the-type-java-util-mapentry-cannot-be-resolved-it-is-indirectly-referenced-fro?rq=1), the error is similar, and it works, the problem wasnt my jdk but my IDE. Ive changed to Kepler and all my problems are gone

Comment: The root cause was that your project didn't have the JDK. Adding the JDK regardless of the IDe you use solved the problem. You didn't configure the IDE accordingly (which tends to happen with Eclipse), but that's another problem...

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I had reconfigured the jdk in the build path multiple times without change, only when I changed the IDE was the problem resolved

Answer (score 2):

You're pointing to the wrong jdk, check jdk path and clean build.

Answer (score 0):

This error only occurs when you don't point to correct jdk. Check jdk path and clean build your project.

Comment: elaborate on clean build?

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error when I moved my project from JRE6 to JRE8 directly in eclipse. To resolve this error, I have installed JRE7 and first compiled the code with JRE7 and later with JRE8. My issue got resolved, give a try if this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

project > properties>libraries> select jre system libraries>edit>installed jre>select >edit> and in jre home try to change lower version of java like JRE home(C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.5.0_22) and JRE name jre1.5.0_22 and finish most probably the problem resolved