# JDK 8 - "The type java.util.Map$Entry cannot be resolved"

Tags: java, eclipse, hashmap, migration, java-8

Im trying to use a HashMap but getting the error:

*"The type java.util.Map$Entry cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files"*

I'm using JDK 8 along with Eclipse.

Anybody know why?

**My code**

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class Analyser {

    public void analyse() throws FileNotFoundException {

        HashMap<String, Integer> candyMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Candy.txt"));

        for(String s=br.readLine(); s!=null; s=br.readLine()) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }       

    }
}
```

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24110620/the-type-java-util-mapentry-cannot-be-resolved-it-is-indirectly-referenced-fro

Comment: What line produces the error?

Comment: Ok so perhaps i need to change my Eclipse version from indigo to luna! il update on whether this is the fix

Comment: Upgrade your Eclipse. Possibly your release doesn't support JDK 8 .

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This was fixed by changing my Eclipse IDE version from indigo to luna. Luna comes with support for Java 8 so all issues have now been resolved.

Comment: Thanks! Made my day! Spent hours trying to figure out same problem with project imported from kepler to helios

Comment: I installed Mars, that too solved the issue.

Comment: Combination of Mars , Java 8 , tomcat 8.0 working on one machine and not working on another machine

Comment: I had that problem when building a Maven project. It was caused by JAVA_HOME pointing to the JRE contained in JDK8. Setting JAVA_HOME to JDK8 directly solved the issue. `maven --version` shows the Java settings of Maven. Perhaps there is a similar mismatch in Eclipse.