# Java: Upgrading to JDK 1.8 java.util.Map$Entry cannot be resolved

Tags: java, migration, java-8

**Situation**: I have a simple java application, which also reads a property file. It used to work fine in JDK 1.7.

**Problem**: After upgrading to JDK 1.8 and Tomcat 8, I get the following error:

```
The type java.util.Map$Entry cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
```

**Things I did**: I updated Eclipse plugins, I upgraded Tomcat 7 to Tomcat 8, and added ec-4.jar.

However, nothing worked, and the error still remains.

Comment: Which version of Eclipse are you using? It is Luna?

Comment: hmmm, could you check the eclipse configuration especially for installed java runtime?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26102115/error-when-using-logmanager-l4j2-with-java-8-java-lang-reflect-annotatedeleme may have an answer already, based off http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26700824/jdk-8-the-type-java-util-mapentry-cannot-be-resolved

Comment: Alexis C. Yes, it is Luna. The problem got resolved, when I downgraded to JDK 1.7 and Tomcat 7. Thanks.