# The type java.util.Map$Entry cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files in property.put

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, servlets, helios

I am getting this error in Properties.put

```
The type java.util.Map$Entry cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
```

Comment: Maybe this can help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26700824/jdk-8-the-type-java-util-mapentry-cannot-be-resolved

Comment: Thank you Luna has been solved the problem :)