# "The type Java.util.Map$Entry cannot be resolved"

Tags: java, tomcat

I have created a web project in eclipse, which works fine, but when i add the Hashmap it gives me the error The type Java.util.Map$Entry canot be resolved.

I have seen many discussions on the same issue but could not get a solution. Can someone help me please.

```
package com.balu.loginApp.bean;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class LoginAuthenitication {
    Map<String, String> users = new HashMap<String, String>();

    public LoginAuthenitication()
    {
        users.put("balu", "Balamurali CL");
        users.put("swathi", "Swathi RL");
    }

    public boolean loginAuthenitications(String userName, String passWord)
    {
        if (passWord== null || passWord.trim() == "")
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
            return true;
}
```

**Stacktrace**

```
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
org/apache/juli/logging/LogFactory at
org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.<clinit>(LifecycleBase.java:37)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
org.apache.juli.logging.LogFactory at
java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381) at
java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) at
sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331) at
java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ...
```

Comment: What version of Java are you using to a) run the program b) compile the program c) run Eclipse?

Comment: Can you also post a full stacktrace? This is a runtime error, right? What servlet container are you using and at which version?

Comment: Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/juli/logging/LogFactory
 at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.<clinit>(LifecycleBase.java:37)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.juli.logging.LogFactory
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
 at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
 ... 1 more

Comment: eclipsee Details:Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.

Version: Indigo Service Release 2
Build id: 20120216-1857

(c) Copyright Eclipse contributors and others 2005, 2012.  All rights reserved.
Visit http://www.eclipse.org/webtools

Comment: Maybe this can help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26700824/jdk-8-the-type-java-util-mapentry-cannot-be-resolved

Comment: The stack trace shows a totally different problem.

Comment: Neither your title nor your code has anything whatsoever to do with your question.

Comment: The function should contain `return passWord != null && !passWord.trim().isEmpty();` as `== ""` is a wrong string comparison (should use `equals`).

Answer (score 0):

Please follow this instructions

Right click on the project.

Click 'Properties'

Go to 'Java Build Path'

And then: 'Libraries'

In there, Click: Add External Jars

Add: ''Path/To/Tomcat/Bin/tomcat-juli.jar

Comment: Hi ,As told I have added the tomact-jul-jar yet the issue exists.

Comment: I created a simple project as below package com.balu.webapplication;

import java.util.Map;

public class HaspMap {
 
 Map<String, String> mapstring = new HaspMap<String, String>();
 

}         even for this the error shows so ..I am not sure why is this happening

Answer (score 0):

After reading the stacktrace you provided , it has nothing to do with `Java.util.Map$Entry`.

error from stacktrace :

`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/juli/logging/LogFactory`

**[possible solution](http://forum.spring.io/forum/springsource-tc-server/tc-server-general/74061-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-org-apache-juli-logging-logfactory)**

Tomcat's `bootstrap.jar` used to reference the file `bin/tomcat-juli.jar` in it's manifest. That is changing since it forced tomcat to use a specific library. Instead, it has to be added to the `-classpath` line. Open your server configuration, and add `tomcat-juli.jar` to the classpath, and it will work.