# The type java.util.Map$Entry cannot be resolved

Tags: java, jar, package

I've a JSP file which needs the class `Map`, which belongs to `javax.script` (if I'm not wrong).

I've imported it, but I'm getting the following error:

```
The type java.util.Map$Entry cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
```

After doing a bit of research, I think it's because I need to have a jar file which contains it, but I don't **know how can I find it** (neither to which jar, nor the place to download it).

Could you explain me **how to find it** (as it would be useful for future cases) or provide a link?

Thank you so much

Comment: Try: `import java.util.Map;`

Comment: I had already imported `java.util.*` @stackoverflowuser2010 =S

Comment: Various other questions related to your compiler error. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26102115/error-when-using-logmanager-l4j2-with-java-8-java-lang-reflect-annotatedeleme

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24110620/the-type-java-util-mapentry-cannot-be-resolved-it-is-indirectly-referenced-fro?lq=1

Comment: I've read them both @stackoverflowuser2010, but don't find anything useful since I'm not using an IDE nor building my code (since it's a JSP). Both my compiler and tomcat6 are using `1.8.0_45` (if not there would be an "minor/major version" error), so i don't understand the problem =(

Comment: Try using a 1.7 compiler?

Comment: I can try, but the target computer has to work with 1.8, so I would need a way to make it work with Java 8..

Comment: One reason might be that Tomcat 6 does not run with Java 8 (nor do some versions of Tomcat 7; I stumbled over that problem myself once): http://stackoverflow.com/a/21322569/694804

Comment: This seems to fit with the answers given in the questions which stackoverflowuser2010 posted @jCoder, thanks so much

Comment: Please @jCoder put it as an anser to accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*(Just for the sake of completeness.)*

One reason might be that Tomcat 6 does not run with Java 8 (nor do some versions of Tomcat 7; I stumbled over that problem myself once):
https://stackoverflow.com/a/21322569/694804

So, it is highly suggested to use a recent version of Tomcat 7.0.x (or even 8) when using Java 8.