# Getting error : The type java.util.Map$Entry cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required

Tags: java, spring, jsp

I am learning Java web application. When I tried an example I am getting error

> The type java.util.Map$Entry cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

My code:

```
package com.tutorialspoint;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/hello")
public class HelloController {

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String printHello(ModelMap model){
    model.addAttribute("message", "Hello Spring MVC Framework!");
    return "hello";
}
}
```

I am referring from  : http://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/spring_mvc_hello_world_example.htm

Please guide me to fix this issue.

Comment: Can you look into http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24110620/the-type-java-util-mapentry-cannot-be-resolved-it-is-indirectly-referenced-fro}

Comment: Yes thanks, but it doesn't worked for me.

Comment: which version of java are you using in this project.

Comment: jdk 1.8.0 and jre 1.8.0

Answer (score 0):

It seems your Eclipse IDE does not support Java 8. You better upgrade your eclipse to `Luna` from which they support Java 8. Please refer this https://www.eclipse.org/community/eclipse_newsletter/2014/june/article1.php