# java.util.Map.Entry cannot be resolved error

Tags: spring, string, dictionary, inversion-of-control, entryset

I tried the following code as

```
package collectconstructor;
import java.util.Iterator;  
import java.util.Map;  
import java.util.Set;  

public class QuestionMap {

private int id;  
private String name;  
private Map<String,String> answers;  


public QuestionMap(int id, String name, Map<String, String> answers) {  
    super();  
    this.id = id;  
    this.name = name;  
    this.answers = answers;  
}  

public void displayInfo(){  
    System.out.println("question id:"+id);  
    System.out.println("question name:"+name);  
    System.out.println("Answers....");  
    Set<Entry<String, String>> set=answers.entrySet();  
    Iterator<Entry<String, String>> itr=set.iterator();  
    while(itr.hasNext()){  
        Entry entry= itr.next();  
        System.out.println("Answer:"+entry.getKey()+" Posted By:"+entry.getValue());  
    }  
}  

}
```

Here in the following code snippet

```
 Set<Entry<String, String>> set=answers.entrySet();  
 Iterator<Entry<String, String>> itr=set.iterator();
```

I got the error as the

Multiple markers at this line

- The method entrySet() from the type Map refers to the missing type 
   Map$Entry
- Entry cannot be resolved to a type

Can anybody explain as Why I am getting this error?

Also I tried importing

```
import java.util.Map.Entry;
```

but got same error..
please help!!

Comment: `Set<Map.Entry<String, String>> set=answers.entrySet();` should work..

Comment: I know it is a while since you asked this, but this answer might be of help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24110620/the-type-java-util-mapentry-cannot-be-resolved-it-is-indirectly-referenced-fro

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Set<Map.Entry<String, String>> set = answers.entrySet();  
Iterator<Map.Entry<String, String>> itr = set.iterator();
```

Here `Map.Entry` is the sub interface of Map. So we will be accessed it by `Map.Entry` name. It provides methods to get key and value.

Comment: It is showing the error that Map.Entry cannot be resolved to a type.

Comment: @NDT I have tested it in eclipse editor, It is not showing any error. Did you also change in `Map.Entry entry= itr.next();` in while loop?  Let me know if it is still showing same error after all these 3 changes.

Comment: Then I think problem is somewhere else, You better edit you question with complete code, then only I will be able to help you.